# Cross-threaded operation not valid error in C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, multithreading

I'm pretty new to C# and all the threading stuff and I'm getting "Cross-threaded operation not valid error" at the moment.

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
    private LinkedList<string> _statusList = new LinkedList<string>();

    private void ReportToStatus(string message)
    {
        _statusList.AddLast(message);\
        // textStatus is a textbox.
        // And this is the exact line that is giving the error:
        textStatus.Lines = _statusList.ToArray();
    }

    private void RunTest()
    {
        // ...

        // Run the test in the background worker.
        bgwTest.RunWorkerAsync(testCase);
    }

    private void bgwTest_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        TestCase testCase = e.Argument as TestCase;

        // ...

        // Run the test.
        switch (testCase.TestType)
        {
            case "TestA":    TestA(testCase);
                             break;
        }

        e.Result = testCase;
    }

    private void TestA(TestCase testCase)
    {
        // ...

            PrintStatistic(statisticsForCoil, testCase.OutputFile);
        }
    }

    private void PrintStatistic(int[] statistics, string outputFile)
    {
        // ...

        ReportToStatus(result);
    }
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there might be a problem in _statusList. You can't write to it from a different thread, only read.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> "The LinkedList class does not support chaining, splitting, cycles,
>   or other features that can leave the list in an inconsistent state.
>   The list remains consistent on a single thread. The only multithreaded
>   scenario supported by LinkedList is multithreaded read operations."

Also, you can't access the UI from a background thread. You need to use the dispatcher to invoke operations onto the UI thread. To do this your code will need to look like this

**WPF**

```
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate
                                   {
                                        textStatus.Lines = _statusList.ToArray();
                                   }));
```

**WinForms**

```
    textStatus.Invoke(new Action(delegate
                                   {
                                        textStatus.Lines = _statusList.ToArray();
                                   }));
```

Comment: Is that a safe way to do it? What would be the most natural approach to update the list and the textbox to show the progress while the background worker is still working?

Comment: That is the safest way to do it, without doing an Invoke there is no way to communicate with the UI thread from the BackgroundWorker while it is running. An Invoke basically moves execution into the associated Thread, in this case the UI thread. When the Invoke is completed, execution moves back to the original calling thread.

Comment: I think `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()` method is for WPF, what is the Windows Forms counterpart?

Comment: Apologies, using winforms you can call Invoke directly from the control. I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: Using `SynchronizationContext` you could have the same code for both **Winforms** and **WPF**. Actually using it in the **WinForms** case will be more thread safe for shutdown scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The `BackgroundWorker` has a dedicated mechanism for updating the UI:
[BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). For example, in your code it could look like this:

```
private void ReportToStatus(string message)
{
    _statusList.AddLast(message);
    // textStatus is a textbox.
    // And this is the exact line that is giving the error:
    bgwTest.ReportProgress(0, _statusList.ToArray());
}

//Assuming this is the method handling bgwTest's ProgressChanged event
private void bgwTest_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     textStatus.Lines = (string[])(e.UserState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the UI from your background worker which will cause that exception. You can use the Dispatcher to schedule an update instead - or more ideally use the background worker to do "background" work only, then do your UI updates when the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event is raised.

Comment: But I would like to update the textbox with the results while the background worker is still working. What should I do for that?